# Safety of removing older kernel images on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package-management, kernel

I try to remove older versions (or maybe rather images) of Ubuntu 14.04. I swiftly went through:

[How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

I have `uname -r` 4.4.0-119-generic version. Is it safe to remove let say, all 3.XX.Y images? And those `linux-signed-image-xxx`, are they pretty much the same as "non-signed" ones and can they also be removed?

(edit:
after a while I noticed, that "Mark for complete removal" of linux-image-number in Synaptic Package Manager also marks linux-image-extra-number and linux-signed-image-number. So it "comes together" somehow.)

I tried to remove `linux-image-extra-3.16.0-70-generic`

Is it normal that it takes 5-10 minutes to remove via Synaptic Package Manager?

Comment: Yes and yes. I keep only the two most recent (and working) kernels. It is good to keep not only the latest kernel (you might get problems with the newest one), but the older kernels can and  should be removed. They are only occupying drive space. And it does take a lot of time to remove kernels and set up the system to be aware of the remaining kernels.

Comment: @sudodus, thank you. Little offtopic question: why did you not give it as answer and used comment? I like green "mark off" button? :-)

Comment: I can give you an answer :-)

Comment: Saving space can be especially useful on older machines or newer SSDs. I am quite surprised that one image is about 200 MB and I have a lot of them. And I confirm, it have taken hours, now and it is not done yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is safe to remove old linux kernels

I keep only the two most recent (and working) kernels. It is good to keep not only the latest kernel (you might get problems with the newest one), but the older kernels can and should be removed. They are only occupying drive space.

### Removing kernels is a slow process

It does take a lot of time to remove kernels and set up the system to be aware of the remaining kernels.

It works well to remove kernels with the Synaptic Package Manager.